# Convert LinQ from SQL statement in C# MongoDB

Tags: c#, mysql, mongodb, linq

I'm working on converting my project from MySQL to MongoDB.
I'm converting a few statements to MongoDB by using LinQ.

Here is my Original Statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(machinelograwdata.Parameter1) AS 'HideSheetCounter', 
    machinelograwdata.Parameter42 AS 'Orders', 
    machinelograwdata.MachineID 
FROM machinelograwdata 
WHERE EventID = '14' 
    AND CONVERT( Parameter35 , DECIMAL) <> 0 
    AND machinelograwdata.StartTime <= ' strSearchingEndDate + ' 
    AND machinelograwdata.StartTime >= ' strSearchingStartDate + ' 
GROUP BY Parameter42 , machinelograwdata.MachineID
```

and I try the following LinQ syntax and I got error:

```
var Temp3 = from c in MachineCollection.AsQueryable()
        where c.StartTime >= DateTime.Parse(strSearchingStartDate)
              && c.StartTime <= DateTime.Parse(strSearchingEndDate)
              && c.EventID == "14"
              && c.Parameter35 != "0"
        group c by new { c.Parameter42, c.MachineID } into grps
        select new
        {
            MachineID = grps.Key.MachineID,
            Orders = grps.Key.Parameter42,
            HideSheetCounter = grps.Count(x => x.Parameter1)
        };
```

Visual Studio raises issues at `select` and `x.Parameter1`
For `x.Parameter1`, the error is `Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'`
but my POCO is

```
[BsonElement("Parameter1")]
public string Parameter1
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

What is my code wrong? Could you give me some hints?
Thank you

Comment: `Count()` expects a predicate (an expression returning `true` for each element you wish to count). Remove that part: `x => x.Parameter1`

Comment: Thank you, @FedericoDipuma.
But if I remove "x => x.Parameter1" , the result is not same with Original Statement Result.

Comment: If you want the same behavior (ignore the `null` values for `Parameter1`) then add that predicate inside `Count()`: `Count(x => x.Parameter1 != null)`

Comment: ah, now i understand more about LinQ based on your `Count()` : `Count(x => x.Parameter1 != null)`
Thank you so much, @FedericoDipuma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Count()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb534807(v=vs.110).aspx) needs a predicate which returns a boolean for each element you want to count satisfing that condition.

To mimic the same behavior of `COUNT(columnName)` you need to provide the method a predicate which excludes `null` values for your field:

```
grps.Count(x => x.Parameter1 != null)
```